# Why is my MVC ViewModel Empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Model:

```
public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class FullPrice
{
    public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model hotel.Models.FullPrice
@foreach(Service service in Model.Services)
{
    //
}
```

My view model is NULL. Why?

Comment: What is your controller code doing?

Comment: You have to initialize it in the controller action before passing to the view. Show the action code.

Comment: FullPrice model = new FullPrice(); return View(model);      this my Action

Comment: you'll need to have some controller actions before you attempt to scaffold your views

Answer (score 2):

Model would be **NULL** because there is no currently existing instance as the view is being executed.

Usually, the way to pass a model instance into a view would be in the corresponding action method like

```
public View myActionMethod()
{
    hotel.Models.FullPrice model = new hotel.Models.FullPrice();
    model.Services = new List<Service>();//Also prevent NULL exception with this property
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not the model what is null, but the `Services`. Change the action code to

```
FullPrice model = new FullPrice
{
    Services = new List<Service>()
};
return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ViewModel code to below

```
public class FullPrice
{
    public FullPrice()
    {
        this.Services = new List<Service>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

so the `Services` property won't be null when you do this

```
FullPrice model = new FullPrice();
```